# How to define constants in Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Is there some special approach for defining constants in Anchor? I tried it normally just before the program ID:

```
pub const MY_CONST: &'static str = "some example str";

declare_id!("MY_PROGRAM_PUBKEY");
```

But then I try to verify if my constants were defined within some of my Anchor instructions:

```
msg! {"My const value: {:#?}", std::env::var("MY_CONST")};
msg! {"My const value: {:#?}", option_env!("MY_CONST")};
```

But I keep getting empty values, I guess it has something to do with the run time.  Is there some "Anchor way" of defining constants or verify if they are actually defined?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mixing up constants and environment variables. You can use constants by just referring to them by name, they don't become environment variables.

For example:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("B5KGifZpdZqPtnC1qgkwjMZB2LBp9seXC5fJXPTN8x4W");

const THE_NUMBER: u8 = 42;

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("The number is: {}!", THE_NUMBER); // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {
}
```

Transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2BxPY6pNU2d6C1hZfBdfvFvDqwxeB14m6LohwLCrZQ4eWnigqr3DUufiuuSyM7f3HavAothwBAZvtVQVAGfjA3Mw?cluster=devnet (notice "The number is: 42!" in the logs)

Example playground: https://beta.solpg.io/63f8a3cf67edfe0f001069d4

Comment: What if `THE_NUMBER`is not defined? how can you handle that case  within the  ìnitialize()` function? That's what I really want to achieve here.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but if you wanted to pass the number into the instruction instead of having it be a constant it'd be like this: https://beta.solpg.io/63fe190f67edfe0f001069d9 Does that help?